# Setting up a Laravel cron job in cPanel

Tags: laravel, cron, cpanel, schedule, laravel-artisan

I have the following function:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('email:users')->everyMinute();
}
```

when I run the command

```
artisan schedule:run
```

it sends an email but when I add the following command to the cpanel as a cron job it doesn't send any email. Cpanel suppose to email me a notification when the cron job is run but I haven't receive a single email.

> php /home/rain/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Where am I doing wrong?

Also when I run the command `artisan schedule:run` it runs it only once. I am very curious why do I have to add `->everyMinute();` if it is not going to run every minute? If I want to send it weekly I can setup the cron job. Why do I have to write to add `->weekly();` in the function if cron job is sending it weekly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Laravel scheduler assumes you have a cronjob every minutes. The scheduler is only useful if you want to have multiple tasks.

Normally you have one single cronjob configured in cPanel and you can set the scheduler to `everyWeek()` and have another task that would be `everyDay()` without having to add of change the cronjobs in your cPanel.

Laravel will automagically know if the task has already been run.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When
>   the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your
>   scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Comment: thanks Pascal for the info. Any idea why the cron job doesn't run? I used it as described `php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: First you can debug this by executing the command manually, ex: `php /abolute-path-to-your-app/artisan schedule:run` and see if there is any error at this point.

Comment: hi Pascal it works now. I found out that /dev/null 2>&1' is used in cron job when you do not want to send email when cron job runs. So, what the command should be exactly to get emails from cpanel when it runs the cron job?

Comment: You have to remove the `>> /dev/null 2>&1` part and set the `MAILTO` to your email. I think there is an interface to do this in cPanel, but make sure to remove the part I said.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php /home/i198yhcgeee/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me:

First try your command without waiting:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/hosting-username/laravel-folder/artisan schedule:run
```

Then, once you checked if it worked, add this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/hosting-username/laravel-folder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5):

This Works for me

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/hosting-username/laravel-folder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null
```

Just Make Sure you use exact version of php to execute schedule

e.g
if your php v is 7.3 then the code will be

```
 /usr/local/bin/ea-php73 /home/hosting-username/laravel-folder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

/usr/local/bin/php /home2/maildoll/demo.maildoll.com/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty >> /dev/null

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. We have to put '&&' in between the path and command. This worked for me

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/hosting-username/laravel-folder/artisan &&  command:my_command >> /dev/null
```